# Npm for "file-system-like" management of private dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to have this setup :

- root is a folder corresponding to a git project
- root/projectA is a node module
- root/projectB is a node module, that needs to require projectA.

#### Some very important constraints

- I don't want to publish any of those node projects to npm.org
- I can not have a different git repository for each project
- projectA changes *all the time* during development, so having to republish it every time I change a file is *not* acceptable
- In the end, I want to be able to "distribute" a zip containing projectB/node_modules/projectA (everything needed to run the code in projectB)

#### Current solution

So, for development, I solve this with a single npm link. So :

- I do *not* declare "projectA" in the package.json of "projectB" (If I did, 'npm install' rightfully complains that the project is not available in npm)
- Every new dev has to do three steps :

  - checkout root
  - cd root/projectB
  - npm link ../projectA

This is becoming painfull, as the number of dependencies grows.
Plus, the dependencies are installed "locally", and linked, so making the "distribution"

#### Problems with potential solutions

From what I understand :

- using a "private repository" like reggie, or an actual npm mirror, would require us to "npm publish" projectB every single time it changes ; that would be unacceptable for development
- git will not work because all of our node projects are in the same git project
- Instinctively, I would love to use relative path in my package.json, but this feature has been denied for a [few years now](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1558) . Which probably means there is an obvious solution, that I'm missing.

*Is there a way to deal with this, without having to publish everything, everytime you change a line ?*

Thanks

Comment: ping, what did you end up doing?  The answers didn't seem to quite answer the problem perfectly.   I'm thinking that if you depend on A at the top level, then B can depend on A but doesn't need to install its own nested version (especially with npm-3's flattened dep tree)

Comment: We used a mix of 'grunt-link', 'npm link', and local dependency ("foo" : "../../foo" is now possible, with some caveats : https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths )

Answer (score 0):

Having a structure like this should just work (I tested it locally):

`root/
   node_modules/
      projectA/
      projectB/`

Also make sure to add `"private": true` in your projects' package.json and add something like

```
"dependencies": {
    "projectA": "*"
},
```

to your projectB's package.json.

Comment: Does root need to be an npm project itself ? Should it define "projectA" and "projectB" as dependencies ?

Comment: The root path doesn't have to have a package.json. You could just require() the project modules from some javascript file in the root path if you wanted to.

Comment: How is "projectB"'s going to know where to look for projectA ? Running "npm install" in projectB will fail, unless I do the 'npm link ../projectA' that I'm trying to avoid.